# Menu not displaying/flashes up momentarily and disappears

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

having an issue with getting an options menu to display from a fragment. If I don't have any of the code in the main activity portion nothing happens. After adding onCreateOptionsMenu to the main activity the icon appears momentarily in the toolbar, but then disappears, almost as if the view is being repainted?

Update:
Removed the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected from the fragment. Corrected the missing @Override on the onOptionsItemSelected in the activity. Issues persist. See updated WallpaperActivity.java below.

Updated WallpaperActivity.java

```
package com.death2all110.blisspapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WallpaperActivity extends Activity {

    public final String TAG = "BlissPapers";
    protected static final String MANIFEST = "wallpaper_manifest.xml";
    protected static final int THUMBS_TO_SHOW = 4;

    /*
     * pull the manifest from the web server specified in config.xml or pull
     * wallpaper_manifest.xml from local assets/ folder for testing
     */
    public static final boolean USE_LOCAL_MANIFEST = false;

    ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> categories = null;
    ProgressDialog mLoadingDialog;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper);


        mLoadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mLoadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mLoadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mLoadingDialog.setMessage("Retreiving wallpapers from server...");

        mLoadingDialog.show();
        new LoadWallpaperManifest().execute();

        UrlImageViewHelper.setErrorDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.drawable.ic_error));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_about:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Wallpaper.wallpapersCreated = 0;
    }

    protected void loadPreviewFragment() {

        Toolbar ab = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setActionBar(ab);


        WallpaperPreviewFragment fragment = new WallpaperPreviewFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }


    public static class WallpaperPreviewFragment extends Fragment {

        static final String TAG = "PreviewFragment";
        WallpaperActivity mActivity;
        View mView;

        public int currentPage = -1;
        public int highestExistingIndex = 0;
        ImageButton back;
        ImageButton next;
        TextView pageNum;
        ThumbnailView[] thumbs;
        protected int selectedCategory = 0; // *should* be <ALL> wallpapers


        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mActivity = (WallpaperActivity) getActivity();
            next(); // load initial page
        }

        public void setCategory(int cat) {
            selectedCategory = cat;
            currentPage = -1;
            next();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            mView = inflater.inflate(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.layout.activity_wallpaper, container, false);

            back = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.backButton);
            next = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.nextButton);
            pageNum = (TextView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.textView1);

            thumbs = new ThumbnailView[THUMBS_TO_SHOW];
            thumbs[0] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView1);
            thumbs[1] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView2);
            thumbs[2] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView3);
            thumbs[3] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView4);



            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    next();
                }
            });

            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    previous();
                }
            });


            return mView;

        }

        public ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> getCategories() {
            return mActivity.categories;
        }

        protected Wallpaper getWallpaper(int realIndex) {
            return getCategories().get(selectedCategory).getWallpapers().get(realIndex);
        }

        protected void setThumbs() {
            for (ThumbnailView v : thumbs)
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            final int numWallpapersInCategory = getCategories().get(selectedCategory)
                    .getWallpapers().size();
            boolean enableForward = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
                final int realIndex = (currentPage * thumbs.length + i);
                if (realIndex >= (numWallpapersInCategory - 1)) {
                    enableForward = false;
                    break;
                }

                Wallpaper w = getWallpaper(realIndex);
                thumbs[i].setOnClickListener(null);
                thumbs[i].getName().setText(w.getName());
                thumbs[i].getAuthor().setText(w.getAuthor());
                UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(thumbs[i].getThumbnail(), w.getThumbUrl(),
                        com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.drawable.ic_placeholder, new ThumbnailCallBack(w, realIndex));
            }

            back.setEnabled(currentPage != 0);
            next.setEnabled(enableForward);
        }

        public void next() {
            getNextButton().setEnabled(false);
            pageNum.setText(getResources().getString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.page) + " " + (++currentPage + 1));

            setThumbs();
        }

        public void previous() {
            pageNum.setText(getResources().getString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.page) + " " + (--currentPage + 1));

            setThumbs();
        }

        protected void skipToPage(int page) {
            if (page < currentPage) {
                while (page < currentPage) {
                    previous(); // should subtract page
                }
            } else if (page > currentPage) {
                while (page > currentPage) {
                    next();
                }
            }
        }


        protected View getThumbView(int i) {
            if (thumbs != null && thumbs.length > 0)
                return thumbs[i];
            else
                return null;
        }

        protected ImageButton getNextButton() {
            return next;
        }

        protected ImageButton getPreviousButton() {
            return back;
        }

        class ThumbnailCallBack implements UrlImageViewCallback {

            Wallpaper wall;
            int index;

            public ThumbnailCallBack(Wallpaper wall, int index) {
                this.wall = wall;
                this.index = index;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Drawable loadedDrawable, String url,
                                 boolean loadedFromCache, boolean error) {

                final int relativeIndex = index % 4;
                if (!error) {
                    getThumbView(relativeIndex).setOnClickListener(
                            new ThumbnailClickListener(wall));
                }
                getThumbView(relativeIndex).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (relativeIndex == 3)
                    getNextButton().setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        class ThumbnailClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
            Wallpaper wall;

            public ThumbnailClickListener(Wallpaper wallpaper) {
                this.wall = wallpaper;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent preview = new Intent(mActivity, Preview.class);
                preview.putExtra("wp", wall.getUrl());
                startActivity(preview);
            }
        }
    }



    public static String getDlDir(Context c) {
        String configFolder = getResourceString(c, com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_download_loc);
        if (configFolder != null && !configFolder.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), configFolder)
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        } else {
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }

    public static String getSvDir(Context c) {
        String configFolder = getResourceString(c, com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_sdcard_dl_location);
        if (configFolder != null && !configFolder.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), configFolder)
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected String getWallpaperDestinationPath() {
        String configFolder = getResourceString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_sdcard_dl_location);
        if (configFolder != null && !configFolder.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), configFolder)
                    .getAbsolutePath();
        }
        // couldn't find resource?
        return null;
    }

    protected String getResourceString(int stringId) {
        return getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(stringId);
    }

    public static String getResourceString(Context c, int id) {
        return c.getResources().getString(id);
    }

    private class LoadWallpaperManifest extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, ArrayList<WallpaperCategory>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> doInBackground(Void... v) {

            try {
                InputStream input = null;

                if (USE_LOCAL_MANIFEST) {
                    input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(MANIFEST);

                } else {
                    URL url = new URL(getResourceString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_manifest_url));
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    // this will be useful so that you can show a typical
                    // 0-100%
                    // progress bar
                    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    // download the file
                    input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                }
                OutputStream output = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(
                        MANIFEST, MODE_PRIVATE);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }


                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

                // file finished downloading, parse it!
                ManifestXmlParser parser = new ManifestXmlParser();
                return parser.parse(new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), MANIFEST),
                        getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception!", e);
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> result) {
            categories = result;

            if (categories != null)
                loadPreviewFragment();

            mLoadingDialog.cancel();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you don't want to edit the Activity menu, just delete the whole `onCreateOptionsMenu()` from **fragment** code. Overriding it from Activity is enough, since the fragment is hosted inside the Activity itself.

Comment: I'm trying to get the menu to appear. I've tried creating the menu from within the activity and from within the fragment. Either way the menu does not show. It appears for a split second and disappears. Even commenting out the code in the Fragment does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out.

I removed

```
Toolbar ab = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setActionBar(ab);
```

from the loadPreviewFragment()

Then removed the Toolbar view from my activity_wallpaper.xml layout
And changed the parent theme in my style.xml from

```
parent=Theme.Material.NoActionBar
```

to

```
parent=Theme.Material
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() method for your fragment, try adding this one line of code:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Android API reference: [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))

I had the same problem when implementing a menu from a fragment

Comment: I've already tried this as well as in the onActivityCreated and onCreateView. The menu appears for a split second and disappears.

Comment: Then I don't know... Unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

To me you should keep only one reference to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Since the fragment is hosted inside the Activity, it's enough to manage options menu from there. So:

1. Delete all instances of `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` from your fragment;
2. Delete all instances of `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` you previously added;
3. In your Activity, just keep:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
     return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   ...
   ```

Note that in your code `@Override` is missing here and there.

That said, why are `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` methods also available for fragments? Because if you have multiple fragments that can be shown in the same Activity, you might want to have each fragment add some items to the Activity `OptionsMenu`.

That is done with `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and there are a lot of questions already answered here on the topic. But, as per what you said, that's not your case. You just want an Activity menu, so forget about the fragment.

The menu disappearing was you calling `menu.clear()`.